# Scheduling Skype for Business Meeting API

Tags: api, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I want to develop an application that able to schedule weekly meeting automatically. So the application will have a database consists list of participants and weekly meeting schedules. How do I schedule a meeting automatically 1 week prior to the meeting?
Which SDK should I use? I've looking for a lot of skype for business SDK but still can't find my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create on own custom solution using [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) and [UCMA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn454984.aspx). Using EWS you can fetch the existing meeting from Exchange server and update it after scheduling conference. Alternatively, you can save your conference schedules in your own database. Download [UCMA SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35463). You will get various samples with SDK to help you schedule/ join meeting.

Sample code to schedule conference using UCMA:

```
var schedule = new ConferenceScheduleInformation();
schedule.Subject = "Your Subject"
schedule.ExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60);
schedule.Participants.Add(new ConferenceParticipantInformation("sipaddress", ConferencingRole.Leader));

//Set schedule properties
schedule.AccessLevel = ConferenceAccessLevel.Everyone;
schedule.AttendanceAnnouncementsStatus = AttendanceAnnouncementsStatus.Disabled;
schedule.AutomaticLeaderAssignment = AutomaticLeaderAssignment.Disabled;
schedule.Description = default(string);
schedule.LobbyBypass = LobbyBypass.Disabled;
schedule.OrganizerData = default(string);
schedule.ParticipantData = default(string);
schedule.PhoneAccessEnabled = false;

schedule.Mcus.Add(new ConferenceMcuInformation(McuType.InstantMessaging));
schedule.Mcus.Add(new ConferenceMcuInformation(McuType.AudioVideo));
schedule.Mcus.Add(new ConferenceMcuInformation(McuType.Meeting));

var conference = await this.ScheduleConferenceAsync(schedule);

//conference.ConferenceId; -> ConferenceId
//conference.ConferenceUri; -> ConferenceUri
//conference.WebUrl;    -> ConferenceWebUrl
```